# Calling select in python

Tags: python, sockets, select

I am trying to write a socket server. The server itself doesn't accomplish anything all that interesting. Right now my problem is that python is complaining about my arguments to select. Here is a snippet of code.

```
    read_client_sockets=[the_socket, clients]
    write_client_sockets=[clients, signals]
    error=[]
    #This is the loop that does most everything.
    while 1:
            #try to find someone who is ready for input
            ready_to_read, ready_to_write, in_error = select.select(all_client_sockets,    write_client_sockets, error)
```

Here is the complaint that I receive from my compiler. I have tried tweaking the arguments and end up getting the same result. Also I want this to run in blocking mode. As far as i know it is okay to not specify a timeout parameter; according to documentation I believe it is optional. Thank you for your time. I apologize for not having something more interesting to consider.

```
File "server.py", line 58, in main
    ready_to_read, ready_to_write, in_error = select.select(all_client_sockets, write_client_sockets, error)
TypeError: argument must be an int, or have a fileno() method.
```

Comment: What are `the_socket`, `clients`, and `signals`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass in three *sequences of file descriptors* as arguments to select, from the names you supply I think that `[clients, signals]` might be some other construct (is clients a list of file descriptors?). In this case you could use `clients+signals` as second argument to `select`.

In other words: Each argument must be a *flat* sequence, no nesting is allowed.

Comment: Thanks. I am still getting used to python. However, I am trying listen to my passive socket to see if it has connections that are ready to be accepted. A socket should be a valid argument for this, but you are right that I am doing something rather awful concerning list. I am not used to a language being so flexible with list, so I grabbed the wrong functionality.

Answer (score 1):

I guess `clients` is an array. Try `read_client_sockets=[the_socket] + clients` instead.