# Select Module: Encountering a TypeError with socket server. [Python]

Tags: python, select, module, typeerror

The problem lies directly with the `select.select` line in my socket server.

```
r_list, w_list, x_list = select.select(U_Connections + [ss], Username_List, [])
```

where:

```
Username_List = []
U_Connections = []
```

The problem lies with `Username_List`.

`Username_List` is only supposed to do one thing, and that is store usernames the server receives. Whenever the server receives data, it checks if it has that username (data received ) in the `Username_List`.

If it's there, it just moves on, and ignores the received data.

If it isn't, it adds the data to the list, and then sends all connected clients the new username. This is where the program crashes.

```
if data:
    translated_data = data.decode()
    print(translated_data)
    print("2")
    if translated_data in Username_List:
        pass
    else:
        translated_data_string = str(translated_data)
        Username_List.append(translated_data_string)    <--- HERE
        print("3")
```

As soon as this stage completes, the while loop re-executes. And in the process encounters an `TypeError`. This occurs whenever anything is added to `w_list`.

What am I doing wrong, how am I supposed to use the `select` module to make this work?

All I need it to do is append usernames to a list, and then send that to everybody if a username it recieves isn't in the existing list.

I've been trying to fix this for a while, and did some looking around, but can't seem to find a fix.

I read this:

> "In other words: Each argument must be a flat sequence, no nesting is
>   allowed."

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9737728/calling-select-in-python) thread. But I don't really understand what is being done wrong.

The full code for the server is on pastebin [here](http://pastebin.com/17f6yVe2)
(Note I have a `except:` catching the `TypeError`)

If someone could please kindly also explain how I am not correctly interpreting the select module, I would be much appreciative. I don't want to ask stupid questions.

Error Encountered:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Owatch\Documents\Unisung\Produced Content\NetSendClient[0.7]\NetSendClient[0.7]\NetSendClient\files\Program_Files\Username_Server.py", line 23, in <module>
    r_list, w_list, x_list = select.select(U_Connections + [ss], Username_List, [])
TypeError: argument must be an int, or have a fileno() method.
```

Comment: Can you please share the full trackback including the exception message?

Comment: So `Username_list` is *not* a list with socket or objects, or integers representing file descriptors? What are you trying to achieve selecting on `Username_List`? The second argument is expected to be a list of files or sockets you want start writing to, and `select()` will tell you which ones are ready.

Comment: I thought Username_list represented an empty list that was waiting to have data to write to something. So that when I inserted a string into the list, and then the while loop passed for i in w_list: it would execute whatever I asked it to. I guess that is an incorrect interpretation...

Comment: No, that is indeed incorrect. You need to give `select` sockets you want to write to, and when `select` returns them in the second argument they are ready to be written to. Then you write your data to be sent directly to those sockets.

Comment: Can I use the same socket that it receives on? Are you saying that select only does what it's told for w_list when it's 'available'. This is confusing for me to understand.

Comment: You can pass in the same sockets, yes. `r_list` only contains those sockets you passed in the first list that are ready to read from, and `w_list` only contains those sockets you passed in the second list that are ready to write to.

Comment: So, wlist will essentially be SS (my designated socket). And when nothing is being read, it will run through wlist, correct?

Comment: You may want to read some tutorials on async socket handling, perhaps, to understand what `select` does. http://www.nightmare.com/medusa/async_sockets.html looks interesting.

Comment: Thanks @MartijnPieters I'll read it right now.