# TypeError argument must be an int or have a fileno() method

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.x, select

Seen here https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=TypeError+argument+must+be+an+int+or+have+a+fileno%28%29+method

But just can't quite find my answer. I am trying out a chat script

Server side runs perfectly fine.

```
# chat_server.py
 
import sys
import socket
import select

HOST = 'localhost' 
SOCKET_LIST = []
RECV_BUFFER = 4096 
PORT = 9009

def chat_server():

    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    server_socket.bind((HOST, PORT))
    server_socket.listen(10)
 
    # add server socket object to the list of readable connections
    SOCKET_LIST.append(server_socket)
 
    print("Chat server started on port " + str(PORT))
 
    while 1:

        # get the list sockets which are ready to be read through select
        # 4th arg, time_out  = 0 : poll and never block
        ready_to_read,ready_to_write,in_error = select.select(SOCKET_LIST,[],[],0)
      
        for sock in ready_to_read:
            # a new connection request recieved
            if sock == server_socket: 
                sockfd, addr = server_socket.accept()
                SOCKET_LIST.append(sockfd)
                print("Client (%s, %s) connected" % addr)
                 
                broadcast(server_socket, sockfd, "[%s:%s] entered our chatting room\n" % addr)
             
            # a message from a client, not a new connection
            else:
                # process data recieved from client, 
                try:
                    # receiving data from the socket.
                    data = sock.recv(RECV_BUFFER)
                    if data:
                        # there is something in the socket
                        broadcast(server_socket, sock, "\r" + '[' + str(sock.getpeername()) + '] ' + data)  
                    else:
                        # remove the socket that's broken    
                        if sock in SOCKET_LIST:
                            SOCKET_LIST.remove(sock)

                        # at this stage, no data means probably the connection has been broken
                        broadcast(server_socket, sock, "Client (%s, %s) is offline\n" % addr) 

                # exception 
                except:
                    broadcast(server_socket, sock, "Client (%s, %s) is offline\n" % addr)
                    continue

    server_socket.close()
    
# broadcast chat messages to all connected clients
def broadcast (server_socket, sock, message):
    for socket in SOCKET_LIST:
        # send the message only to peer
        if socket != server_socket and socket != sock :
            try :
                socket.send(message)
            except :
                # broken socket connection
                socket.close()
                # broken socket, remove it
                if socket in SOCKET_LIST:
                    SOCKET_LIST.remove(socket)
 
if __name__ == "__main__":

    sys.exit(chat_server())
```

But client

```
import sys
import socket
import select
 
def chat_client():

    host = "127.0.0.1"
    port = 9009
     
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.settimeout(2)
     
    # connect to remote host
    try :
        s.connect((host, port))
    except :
        print('Unable to connect')
        sys.exit()
     
    print('Connected to remote host. You can start sending messages')
    sys.stdout.write('[Me] '); sys.stdout.flush()
     
    while 1:
        socket_list = [sys.stdin, s]
        potential_errs=[]
        
        # Get the list sockets which are readable
        ready_to_read,ready_to_write, in_error = select.select(socket_list , host, int(1))
         
        for sock in ready_to_read:             
            if sock == s:
                # incoming message from remote server, s
                data = sock.recv(4096)
                if not data :
                    print('\nDisconnected from chat server')
                    sys.exit()
                else :
                    #print data
                    sys.stdout.write(data)
                    sys.stdout.write('[Me] '); sys.stdout.flush()     
            
            else :
                # user entered a message
                msg = sys.stdin.readline()
                s.send(msg)
                sys.stdout.write('[Me] '); sys.stdout.flush() 

if __name__ == "__main__":

    sys.exit(chat_client())
```

Has run from cmd, not IDLE because of issues (read something about it relating to my issue)

Traceback

```
line 50 in module

    sys.exit(chat_client())

line 28 in chat_client

    ready_to_read,ready_to_write, in_error = select.select(socket_list , host, int(1))

TypeError: argument must be an int or have a fileno() method
```

Comment: See this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9737728/calling-select-in-python

Comment: `ready_to_read,ready_to_write, in_error = select.select(socket_list, [], [])`,     if you want the operation to timeout, add another argument: `select.select(socket_list, [], [], 1)` - that will timeout after one second.

Comment: Tried as you said, Had exception` OSError`. I'm assuming it's because the second argument is not a socket and tries to connect to that.                        As it raises` win error 10038 attempt connection on not a socket.`     Tried to change argument 2 to host but then the     `TypeError: argument must be an int or have a fileno() method` would come back

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`select` doesn't work with non-socket objects on Windows. For more information see the [documentation about select.select](https://docs.python.org/3/library/select.html#select.select), where it mentions that:

> File objects on Windows are not acceptable, but sockets are. On Windows, the underlying `select()` function is provided by the WinSock library, and does not handle file descriptors that don’t originate from WinSock.