# Determine OS of remote machine using pings

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, operating-system, ping

I am trying to figure out how to find which operating system a remote machine
is running using the ping method.

I don't know how to get the TTL number and look at a list to find what OS it uses.

```
ping 19.217.64.1
Pinging 19.217.64.1 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 19.217.64.1: bytes=32 time=3ms TTL=254
Reply from 19.217.64.1: bytes=32 time=3ms TTL=254
Reply from 19.217.64.1: bytes=32 time=5ms TTL=254
Reply from 19.217.64.1: bytes=32 time=4ms TTL=254

Ping statistics for 19.217.64.1:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 3ms, Maximum = 5ms, Average = 3ms
```

Answer (score 1):

Here there is an implementation of the ping in python:

https://gist.github.com/chidea/955cea841e5c76a7e5ee8aa02234409d

Look at the receive_ping function. The TTL is the 9th byte of the received packet (index 8). So I print the TTL in that function:

```
def receive_ping(my_socket, packet_id, time_sent, timeout):
# Receive the ping from the socket.
time_left = timeout
while True:
    started_select = time.time()
    ready = select.select([my_socket], [], [], time_left)
    how_long_in_select = time.time() - started_select
    if ready[0] == []: # Timeout
        return
    time_received = time.time()
    rec_packet, addr = my_socket.recvfrom(1024)
    print ("TTL:", rec_packet[8]) # IT PRINT THE TTL! HAVE A NICE DAY :)
    icmp_header = rec_packet[20:28]
    type, code, checksum, p_id, sequence = struct.unpack(
        'bbHHh', icmp_header)
    if p_id == packet_id:
        return time_received - time_sent
    time_left -= time_received - time_sent
    if time_left <= 0:
        return
```

Comment: it works for most of it but it gets trouble  ready = select.select([my_socket], [], [], time_left)     and says it must be a int or have a fileno() method

Comment: Do you use Windows? If yes read this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33777308/typeerror-argument-must-be-an-int-or-have-a-fileno-method