# argument must be an int, or have a fileno() method - select

Tags: python, select

I have to build a chat in python for a school project and I've been stuck on this error for a couple of pf days now I don't get what is the problem and how to fix it

I've tried looking in the internet changing my code and asking my friends but I wasn't able to solve it 
thanks in advance to all the helpers

the problematic part:

```
def main():
    server_socket = open_server_connection
    while True:
        time.sleep(0.5)
        # updating the sockets lists
        rlist, wlist, xlist = select.select([server_socket] + open_client_sockets, open_client_sockets, [])
        for current_socket in rlist:
           #checking whether the socket is able to send messages
            if current_socket is server_socket:
                #checking if its a new connection
                (new_socket, address) = server_socket.accept()
                open_client_sockets.append(new_socket)
                unnamed_clients.append(open_client_sockets[-1])
                print "new client connected. \n"
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/USER/Pictures/noya diy/summer cyber/summer_hw_noya_server.py", line 339, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/USER/Pictures/noya diy/summer cyber/summer_hw_noya_server.py", line 246, in main
    rlist, wlist, xlist = select.select([server_socket] + open_client_sockets, open_client_sockets, [])
TypeError: argument must be an int, or have a fileno() method
```

Comment: What's the first `select` in `select.select(...)`…?

Comment: is `open_server_connection` a function? If so, you need to call it instead of assigning it to `server_socket`

Comment: @deceze Presumably, it's the `select` module from the standard library.

Comment: Are you running this on Windows?

Comment: have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/q/33777308/8824174 . Is this on windows?

Comment: open_server_connection is a function :
def open_server_connection():
    server_socket = socket.socket()
    server_socket.bind(('127.0.0.1', 23))
    server_socket.listen(5)
    #opening socket connection and listening for clients requests
    print "Server running \n"
    return server_socket

Comment: I'm running it on windows but its python's built-in select